# View-to-Model formatters in Rivets.js

Tags: data-binding, rivets.js

Loving Rivets.js for it's power yet simplicity. However, how to define formatters that take a view-property and format it to a model-property? To my understanding Formatters are meant to operate the other way around, i.e.: from Model to view.

Are View to Model formatters supported somehow, or does this have to be hacked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature that was brought in to Rivets.js **0.4.2**. Big thanks to GMFlash and mdekmetzian on GitHub for implementing it.

Basically you just define bidirectional formatters as an object instead of a single function. When a formatter is defined as a single function, Rivets assumes it to be in the read direction only. When a formatter is defined as an object, Rivets uses it's `read` and `publish` functions to effectively serialize and de-serialize a value.

```
rivets.formatters.date = {
  read: function(value) {
    return value.format("DD/MM/YYYY")
  },
  publish: function(value) {
    return moment(value, "DD/MM/YYYY")
  }
}
```

You can also chain bidirectional formatters with any other formatters, and in any order. They read from left to right, and publish from right to left (skipping any read-only formatters when publishing the value back to the model).

Apologies for the lacking documentation. The homepage doesn't reflect at all the current feature set of Rivets.js and needs to be updated to include added features such as this.

Comment: Thanks. Explains why `rivets.formatters.number = f(v) { return +v }` didn't coerce the value to a Number in the model.

Comment: So this is what we should use for l18n a rivets-based app?

Comment: Whenever I do this, it won't let me update it without going crazy on key up... :-/

Comment: For some reason rv-value is bound onKeyUp and it won't hardly let me type without moment trying to format it pre-maturely... any tips? I'm new to Rivets!